# Reduce console verbosity

Tags: tensorflow, keras, openmp

I am running some training and prediction with Keras/TensorFlow and I get some OMP information that I do not need.

```
2019-05-20 12:11:45.625897: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:71] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best p
erformance.
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22400 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22428 thread 2 bound to OS proc set 2
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22429 thread 3 bound to OS proc set 3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22430 thread 4 bound to OS proc set 4
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22431 thread 5 bound to OS proc set 5
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22432 thread 6 bound to OS proc set 6
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22433 thread 7 bound to OS proc set 7
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22434 thread 8 bound to OS proc set 8
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22435 thread 9 bound to OS proc set 9
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22436 thread 10 bound to OS proc set 10
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22437 thread 11 bound to OS proc set 11
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 22357 tid 22438 thread 12 bound to OS proc set 0
```

How can I remove this extra verbosity?

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: As (the vastly more qualified to talk about this topic than me) [Jim Cownie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1900441) points out, this output appears to be due to having `KMP_AFFINITY` defined with the attribute `verbose`. See [The `KMP_AFFINITY` Environment Variable](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-thread-affinity-interface-linux-and-windows#KMP_AFFINITY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE) and set the environment variable accordingly (the default value is `noverbose,respect,granularity=core,none,0,0`).

(likely wrong information below)

---

I think those messages should go away if you disable the OpenMP warnings setting the environment variable `KMP_WARNINGS` to `off` or `0`. From a shell:

```sh
$ KMP_WARNINGS=off python program.py
```

Or from Python itself, before OpenMP is initialized:

```py
import os
os.environ['KMP_WARNINGS'] = 'off'
```

Comment: It is not clear to me that his comes from KMP_WARNINGS; it looks more like output from KMP_AFFINITY=...,verbose.I think the thing to do is to set KMP_SETTINGS=1 which will show you all of the incoming OpenMP envirables, Then you can see what is set and unset it. Details of all the envirables are at https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-supported-environment-variables (you need to scroll down for the KMP_* ones)

Comment: @JimCownie Well I was pulling the thread from this file: [`kmp_affinity.cpp`](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/openmp/blob/release_80/runtime/src/kmp_affinity.cpp), I imagine those messages com from those `KMP_INFORM(BoundToOSProcSet, ...`. From digging a bit into it I got the impression that `KMP_WARNINGS` would disable `KMP_INFORM` messages but I'm not sure. I'm seeing now however there is that variable `__kmp_affinity_verbose` controlling it, not sure how that is configured.

Comment: @JimCownie Right, no, it is controlled by [`KMP_AFFINITY`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-thread-affinity-interface-linux-and-windows#KMP_AFFINITY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE), setting it to `noverbose,<type>[,...]` I suppose.

Comment: @jdehesa, do you know how to remove the warning `2019-05-20 12:11:45.625897: I tensorflow/...` ?

Comment: @GDG Ah right, you can filter those out with the environment variable `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL`, setting it to `2` or `3` ([see here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1258#issuecomment-261365022)).