# Keras: is KMP_AFFINITY a critical output?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My main concern is if the message "KMP_AFFINITY" is something I should react about. The problem doesnt occur on my laptop with CPU, but only on my PC with GPU. First I tried to run my own Keras implementation but received some warnings. Then I found some simple cnn code from [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/adventuresinML/adventures-in-ml-code/master/keras_cnn.py) to see if the same warnings occured.

I tried to search through the internet, but what I did not understand from those replies, was if its a critical warning and if not, how to get rid of it. Am I missing some packages or something else? The output from anaconda prompt is shown below. After a while the script continues and after some time finishes.

I found one solution to remove the warnings ([stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224689/reduce-console-verbosity) by including:

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_WARNINGS'] = 'off'
```

But does the warnings mean something important or?

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/10
2019-09-13 08:36:03.426583: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:145]
 This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) MKL-DNN to use the following
CPU instructions in performance critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in non-MKL-DNN operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriat
e compiler flags.
2019-09-13 08:36:03.525592: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:115
] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 12. Tune using inter_o
p_parallelism_threads for best performance.
OMP: Info #212: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
OMP: Info #210: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid leaf 11 info
OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: 0-11
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 12 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
OMP: Info #179: KMP_AFFINITY: 1 packages x 6 cores/pkg x 2 threads/core (6 total
 cores)
OMP: Info #214: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc to physical thread map:
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 0 maps to package 0 core 0 thread 0
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 1 maps to package 0 core 0 thread 1
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 2 maps to package 0 core 1 thread 0
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 3 maps to package 0 core 1 thread 1
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 4 maps to package 0 core 2 thread 0
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 5 maps to package 0 core 2 thread 1
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 6 maps to package 0 core 3 thread 0
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 7 maps to package 0 core 3 thread 1
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 8 maps to package 0 core 4 thread 0
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 9 maps to package 0 core 4 thread 1
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 10 maps to package 0 core 5 thread 0
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 11 maps to package 0 core 5 thread 1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 11860 thread 0 bound to OS proc set
0
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 8300 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 2

OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 13076 thread 2 bound to OS proc set
4
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 11736 thread 3 bound to OS proc set
6
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 12028 thread 4 bound to OS proc set
8
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 12700 thread 5 bound to OS proc set
10
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 12608 thread 6 bound to OS proc set
1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 12232 thread 7 bound to OS proc set
3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 3580 thread 8 bound to OS proc set 5

OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 11228 thread 9 bound to OS proc set
7
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 13292 thread 10 bound to OS proc set
 9
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 11672 thread 11 bound to OS proc set
 11
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 12708 thread 12 bound to OS proc set
 0
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 12464 thread 13 bound to OS proc set
 2
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 11448 thread 14 bound to OS proc set
 4
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 11800 thread 15 bound to OS proc set
 6
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 3800 thread 16 bound to OS proc set
8
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 10096 thread 17 bound to OS proc set
 10
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 9532 thread 18 bound to OS proc set
1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 5248 thread 19 bound to OS proc set
3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 2600 thread 20 bound to OS proc set
5
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 7976 thread 21 bound to OS proc set
7
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 12804 thread 22 bound to OS proc set
 9
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 1700 thread 23 bound to OS proc set
11
  128/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 7:16 - loss: 2.3163 - acc: 0
.0547OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 11852 thread 24 bound to OS pro
c set 0
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 12864 thread 25 bound to OS proc set
 2
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 12724 thread 26 bound to OS proc set 4
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 11544 thread 27 bound to OS proc set 6
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 13024 thread 28 bound to OS proc set 8
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 12848 tid 3372 thread 29 bound to OS proc set
10
...
42624/60000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0207 - acc: 0.
42752/60000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0208 - acc: 0.
42880/60000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0208 - acc: 0.
43008/60000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0208 - acc: 0.
43136/60000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0208 - acc: 0.
43264/60000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 11s - loss: 0.0208 - acc: 0.
43392/60000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 10s - loss: 0.0209 - acc: 0.
43520/60000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 10s - loss: 0.0209 - acc: 0.
43648/60000 [====================>.........] - ETA: 10s - loss: 0.0208 - acc: 0.
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224689/reduce-console-verbosity) proposed solution:

```
import os
os.environ['KMP_WARNINGS'] = 'off'
```